# Despite the fact that

Tags: phrase-usage, conjunctions, clauses

My teacher tells me that if I can't change a clause into a noun phrase, I can use the phrase 'despite the fact that' and then write the whole clause, because  it's always right. Is it true?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. "Despite the fact that" is a "get-out clause" if you find "despite" tricky to use. An -ing form of a verb is required after "despite".

Consider converting:

> Estate agents are very unpopular *but* their work is important.

To use "despite" instead of "but"

> Estate agents are very unpopular *despite their work being* important.

This is not an easy construction. Therefore we can simplify by using "despite the fact that" and maintaining our original clause.

> Estate agents are very unpopular *despite the fact that* their work is important.

Note that this is also true in "in spite of" versus "in spite of the fact that".